# Using Jquery form plugin asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code in the View:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit();
});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostData","Home",FormMethod.Post)) {

 <input type="text" name="name" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Then in the controller I have this method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void PostData(string name)
    {
        //do smoething with name
    }
```

The problem is that I get redirected the url /home/PostData when submitting the form.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ajaxSubmit()` submits the form immediately. You need `ajaxForm()` in order to AJAXify an existing form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm();
});
```

once a form has been AJAXified you could later force its submission with `$('#myForm').ajaxSubmit();` or simply leave it to the user to press the submit button.

Also the way you have defined your form it doesn't seem to have an id. So your `$('#myForm')` selector is unlikely to return anything. You might want to assign an id to your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) 
{
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

or if you don't want to assign unique id to the form you could AJAXify all forms on the current view by adapting your jQuery selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').ajaxForm();
});
```